# Why am I unable to login to Play Store app after password reset when I can login with the same password in the desktop version?

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, 2-step-verification

It's almost an hour and a half I had reset my password on Gmail and selected log me out of all devices. So for which I need to re-login to Play Store in order to view my apps. But the problem is that the Play Store is not accepting the new password.

I can log in to Gmail as well as the desktop version of the Play Store, the problem is only with the app version. (When I enter the same password for the [Desktop version of play store](https://play.google.com/store) it even sends the PIN which is required for 2 step verification).

In the app version, it says the Email or password you entered is incorrect.

Comment: Password changes should apply instantly, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

At first, I verified that I was entering the exact password by doing a copy-paste. Once done, I later head to [Google Help](http://help.google.com) and after reading their FAQ's, I chose Contact us and within a few seconds, there was a Google Technical help wherein for him also it was a strange situation and later with some research with the problem he asked me to do is Factory Reset + Account Recovery.

After doing the above, my problem got solved and I was back into Gmail with both the mail IDs online.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the Google account and again adding it using the new password. That should work out.

Go to Settings - Account - Google - now select from the options tab to remove the Google Account. After this, go to Settings - Account and select Google and then add the account using a new password.

Comment: Under the settings there is no Account there is only notifications,general,User control,about.

Comment: @user285oo6 He means the settings app of your phone. Not the play store...

Comment: @SuperThomasLab already tried that and then It was not accepting the password and now when I have completely removed the two accounts from Google I am unable to sign into any one of them

Comment: @user285oo6: what happens when you tried logging in to gmail/play store from the browser on the mobile?

Comment: @Rajat Appreciate for your trial